# How to cmake generate an Xcode project in a nix shell?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cmake, nix

I am on macOS (x86_64-darwin) trying to generate an Xcode project with CMake in a nix shell and get the error below.

Generating the same project using the default generator (i.e. running `cmake -B builds`) works fine.

I've tried adding `xcodebuild6` from the `nixpkgs` repo as a `nativeBuildInput` but had no success there.

I'm hoping it's something obvious like me needing to use some darwin specific version of `mkShell`...

Another potential issue I thought might be having to add Xcode.app as a dependency but I can't find any guidance on how to do that.

There's a few things I want to avoid:

- Write a custom toolchain file for CMake.
- Disable the nix sandbox.
- Run an impure nix shell.

[Here's]((https://github.com/ianacaburian/journix/tree/develop/juce-flakes) the repo dir (it's very simple/small)

Here's the error:

```
(nix:juce-flakes-shell-env) Ians-iMac:juce-flakes iancaburian$ cmake -G Xcode -B builds
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 11.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld - broken
CMake Error at /nix/store/24s6vjb6prbysn2a26myhcyx9zzck9kz-cmake-3.26.4/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.xcodeproj build -target cmTC_8af3a -parallelizeTargets -configuration Debug -hideShellScriptEnvironment && 2023-08-29 03:27:29.942 xcodebuild[56843:14398090] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
    Command line invocation:
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.xcodeproj build -target cmTC_8af3a -parallelizeTargets -configuration Debug -hideShellScriptEnvironment
    
    User defaults from command line:
        HideShellScriptEnvironment = YES
        IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
    
    Computing target dependency graph and provisioning inputs
    
    Create build description
    Build description signature: 933e06fe4cff6730bc71e78ad1f7dac5
    Build description path: /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build/XCBuildData/933e06fe4cff6730bc71e78ad1f7dac5.xcbuilddata
    
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.12, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.3.99.
    CreateBuildDirectory /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build
        cd /Users/iancaburian/Repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.xcodeproj
        builtin-create-build-directory /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build
    
    CreateBuildDirectory /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/Debug
        cd /Users/iancaburian/Repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.xcodeproj
        builtin-create-build-directory /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/Debug
    
    CreateBuildDirectory /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug
        cd /Users/iancaburian/Repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.xcodeproj
        builtin-create-build-directory /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug
    
    /Users/iancaburian/Repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.12, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.3.99. (in target 'cmTC_8af3a' from project 'CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE')
    WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build/cmTC_8af3a.build/Debug/Objects-normal/x86_64/cmTC_8af3a.LinkFileList (in target 'cmTC_8af3a' from project 'CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE')
        cd /Users/iancaburian/Repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i
        write-file /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build/cmTC_8af3a.build/Debug/Objects-normal/x86_64/cmTC_8af3a.LinkFileList
    
    CompileC /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build/cmTC_8af3a.build/Debug/Objects-normal/x86_64/testCCompiler.o /Users/iancaburian/Repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/testCCompiler.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'cmTC_8af3a' from project 'CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE')
        cd /Users/iancaburian/Repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i
        clang -x c -target x86_64-apple-macos10.12 -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-return-type -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wno-non-literal-null-conversion -Wno-objc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -DCMAKE_INTDIR\=\"Debug\" -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -Wno-comma -Wno-block-capture-autoreleasing -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -I/Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/Debug/include -I/Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build/cmTC_8af3a.build/Debug/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build/cmTC_8af3a.build/Debug/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build/cmTC_8af3a.build/Debug/DerivedSources -F/Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/Debug -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build/cmTC_8af3a.build/Debug/Objects-normal/x86_64/testCCompiler.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build/cmTC_8af3a.build/Debug/Objects-normal/x86_64/testCCompiler.dia -c /Users/iancaburian/Repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/testCCompiler.c -o /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build/cmTC_8af3a.build/Debug/Objects-normal/x86_64/testCCompiler.o
    
    Ld /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/Debug/cmTC_8af3a normal (in target 'cmTC_8af3a' from project 'CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE')
        cd /Users/iancaburian/Repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld -Xlinker -reproducible -target x86_64-apple-macos10.12 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -L/Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug -L/Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/Debug -F/Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug -F/Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/Debug -filelist /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build/cmTC_8af3a.build/Debug/Objects-normal/x86_64/cmTC_8af3a.LinkFileList -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/build/cmTC_8af3a.build/Debug/Objects-normal/x86_64/cmTC_8af3a_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/Debug/cmTC_8af3a
    ld: unknown option: -Xlinker
    
    ** BUILD FAILED **
    
    
    The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/iancaburian/repos/journix/juce-flakes/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Osfo2i/Debug/cmTC_8af3a normal (in target 'cmTC_8af3a' from project 'CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE')
    (1 failure)
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: `.../ld` is a **linker**, not a *compiler*. Not sure why your environment contains such compiler setting.